# how to use Modernizr in VueJS Webpack project

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, modernizr, vuetify.js

Does anyone have a simple tutorial to bundle and use Modernizr in a VueJs Webpack project?

I use the default Webpack project of VueJS with monofile components.
I want it all bundled.

For precision i want to use inputtypes.date in a majority of forms and avoid display vuetify date picker when on mobile browser with date picker support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not used modernizr, but based on my experience using webpack, i think you can use existing modernizr loaders, i.e [webpack-modernizr-loader](https://github.com/itgalaxy/webpack-modernizr-loader)

As its docs says your can use `.modernizrrc.js` config file, for example:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {
  options: [
    "setClasses"
  ],
  "feature-detects": [
    "inputtypes"
  ]
};
```

adding webpack rule and alias to your `webpack.config.js` (note you need point to right place, where config file stored in alias path.resolve...):

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: "webpack-modernizr-loader",
        test: /\.modernizrrc\.js$/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      modernizr$: path.resolve(__dirname, "/path/to/.modernizrrc.js")
    }
  }
}
```

then you can import your `modernizr` and use it like this:

```
import modernizr from 'modernizr';

if(modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I have problems with dependencies: `These dependencies were not found:

* fs in ./node_modules/export-files/index.js, ./node_modules/file/lib/file.js and 4 others
* lib/generate-banner in ./node_modules/modernizr/lib/build.js
* package in ./node_modules/modernizr/lib/build.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save fs lib/generate-banner package
`

Installing does not help though, maybe also because I get this when trying to install... `fatal: Could not read from remote repository.` 
But anyway shouldnt the webpack-modernizr-loader take care of its dependencies?

Comment: Long time ago, but I currently run into the same problem. Workaround: Install modernizr globally by adding -g option solved it for me.