# CSS - Display Alternative Image When Original Not Supported

Tags: css, image, webp

I'm building a website and I want to use the `WebP` format for my images. I know than [not all browsers support it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=webp), so I want to display an alternative `JPG` image if `WebP` is not supported. I have a `div` with this class applied to it:

```
.my-class{
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(89, 167, 255, 0.5), rgba(0, 31, 62, 0.7)), url('../assets/images/image.webp');
}
```

I want to add something to this class that displays an alternative `image.jpg` if the website is used on a browser that doesn't support `WebP`. **How can I achieve this (With pure CSS)?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good guide for what you want to 
obtain on CSS Tricks:

https://css-tricks.com/using-webp-images/

Pure css isn´t the best way to solve this,
you´ve to detect if the client supports webp 
and css won´t do this.

So you need as example Modenizr to detect if the 
client supports webp or not.

https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses

After you´ve choosen what you need (webp) you will get 
a small js file. 
Add it to your page like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <script src="js/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
  </head>
```

Now basicly you´ll create your class like this:

```
 .no-webp .elementWithBackgroundImage {
  background-image: url("image.jpg");
  }

 .webp .elementWithBackgroundImage{
  background-image: url("image.webp");
  }
```

There is even a solution for clients that have deactivated js but 
this needs a little inline script which can be found in the CSS Tricks article as well.

Your class would look like this:

```
.no-webp-my-class .elementWithBackgroundImage{
background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(89, 167, 255, 0.5), rgba(0, 31, 62, 0.7)), url('../assets/images/image.jpg');
 }
.my-class .elementWithBackgroundImage{
background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(89, 167, 255, 0.5), rgba(0, 31, 62, 0.7)), url('../assets/images/image.webp');
 }
```

**Edit**

There is another way but it needs some work and php.
Basicly it´s nothing more than a browser switch and you have to spilt up 
your stylesheet.

To make things easier create a file named stylesheet.php or whatever 
and declare the header:

```
<?php 
  header("Content-type: text/css;charset=UTF-8");
```

to save some work this soulution will read the existing .css file
and give it out as an echo:

```
<?php 
  header("Content-type: text/css;charset=UTF-8"); 
  $file_read = fopen("stylesheet.css","r+");
    while(! feof($file_read))  {
    $css= fgets($file_read);
    echo "$css";
    }
```

Now all classes which use a webp image can be switched by checking 
if the browser exepts webp.

```
if( strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'image/webp' ) !== false ) {
// webp is supported!
 }
 else {
 // webp is not supported!
}
```

Which would lead to this:

```
<?php 
  header("Content-type: text/css;charset=UTF-8"); 
  $file_read = fopen("stylesheet.css","r+");
    while(! feof($file_read))  {
    $css= fgets($file_read);
    echo "$css";
    }
if( strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'image/webp' ) !== false ) {
 echo "
 .my-class .elementWithBackgroundImage{
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(89, 167, 255, 0.5), rgba(0, 31, 62, 0.7)), url('../assets/images/image.webp');
  }";

 }
 else {
 echo "
 .my-class {
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(89, 167, 255, 0.5), rgba(0, 31, 62, 0.7)), url('../assets/images/image.jpg');
  }";
 }
 ?>
```

**Edit**

I´ve forgotten something:
You can add the .php file like a normale .css file 
to your html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.php" media="screen"/>
```

Comment: This will only work for background images. It is better to define a source set for an image in the HTML so as not to limit the style properties which can be applied.

Comment: This was the question and the solution in html was already given in the answer befor mine and can also be found in the css tricks article. But your right again ;)

Comment: sorry I do not mean to harp on you. Your answer is certainly not wrong, and I very much appreciate you leaving the HTML part out and expanding on the rest. That’s the right way to do it.

Comment: Everything is fine, this is a community or not? ;) My english is not the best anymore, maybe my sentence was formulated a little harsch.

Comment: Not at all! Keep it up!

Comment: If this worked, it would've been the solution for me. The problem is: It doesn't work. The element that should have the background shows no background at all. Might the reason be that I'm using `Vue.js`, so the script runs before the `Vue.js` script and nothing shows up?

Comment: Someone run into this problem befor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221027/how-to-use-modernizr-in-vuejs-webpack-project, the solution seems to be the webpack-modernizr-loader: https://github.com/itgalaxy/webpack-modernizr-loader. But your thought perhaps be right.

Comment: @AmeerTaweel i´ve added another solution.

Comment: @ThorstenWolske The problem is that in `Vue.js` you type the `CSS` inside the `.vue` file. Do you have an idea on how to make the `PHP` read that `CSS`?

Comment: My first thougt would only lead to more ad more work. @AmeerTaweel you could copy and paste the pure css to the "stylesheet.php" and add the <link> to the html.

Comment: So it's going to become something like this?:
`<?php $css= fgets($file_read); echo "$css";
     if( strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'image/webp' ) !== false ) {
         echo ".my-class .elementWithBackgroundImage{ background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(89, 167, 255, 0.5), rgba(0, 31, 62, 0.7)), url('../assets/images/image.webp');
         }";
    } else { echo ".my-class { background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(89, 167, 255, 0.5), rgba(0, 31, 62, 0.7)), url('../assets/images/image.jpg'); }"; }
 ?>` Sorry for the bad formatting but I can't do better in comments.

Comment: Don´t worry, this way it wont work. The php header must be defined as in the example. Since we´re only passing by some css in the script there is no need to read in the other files so the part you can remove is the ` $file_read = fopen("stylesheet.css","r+");
    while(! feof($file_read))  {
    $css= fgets($file_read);
    echo "$css";
    }`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the HTML `picture` element to define sources for your image, like so:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="image.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="image.jpg" type="image/jpeg"> 
  <img src="image.jpg">
</picture>
```

In this case, if a browser supports `webp` images, the image will serve as such, otherwise it will resort to the classic `jpg` version. You will obviously need to have both versions present.

If you want a pure css solution you will need to use feature detection (`media`) for each individual browser that either does or does not support `webp` (depending on the method) and change the image accordingly. I’d suggest option one.

Comment: This works actually, and is really useful, but in my case I need to implement it in CSS because I'm making a "Parallax Scrolling" effect and so I need CSS.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by pure CSS with `image-set()`.

**Edit January 2023** 
The `type` option is not implemented properly in Chromium yet. So it cannot be used as of now. But I am leaving this answer here, so that in the future, it could be useful.
**Edit January 2023**

See mdn web docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image/image-set

Example:

```css
.box {
  background-image: url("large-balloons.jpg");
  background-image: -webkit-image-set(
    "large-balloons.avif" type("image/avif"),
    "large-balloons.jpg" type("image/jpeg")
  );
  background-image: image-set(
    "large-balloons.avif" type("image/avif"),
    "large-balloons.jpg" type("image/jpeg")
  );
}
```

In this example, the fallback is jpg and the desired modern format is avif. The `image-set()` let's you define an order of preference.

And for all browsers that do not know `image-set()` yet, you place a `url()` **before** `image-set()` as fall-back, as shown in the example.